# Como abrir el explorador de archivos en una app Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Saludos

Tengo una aplicación en android para descargar archivos, el problema consta de que necesito que al descargar el archivo se **habrá el explorador de archivo predeterminado del sistema** en el folder donde se descargo mi archivo para que el usuario pueda visualizar su archivo.

**El problema no es la descarga**, ya la aplicación se encarga de descargarla y si voy al explorador de archivos manualmente allí se encuentra.

Comment: Enmanuel, te invito a poner un ejemplo minimo y verificable para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Puedes ver este enlace para saber como https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. De otra forma tu pregunta podria ser puesta en espera o cerrada. Saludos!

Comment: "al descargar el archivo se habrá el explorador de archivo predeterminado del sistema", ¿que tipo de archivo?

Comment: un mp4, para que el decida si quiere reproducirlo o moverlo a otra ubicación de su preferencia

Answer (score 1):

Podrias probar con un Intent

```
public void openFolder(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
         + "/myFolder/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma puede ser:

```
public void openFolder(){
    Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tuCarpeta");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "application/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Me ayudó también el post de T.Todua https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611757/how-to-simply-open-directory-folder

Un saludo.